# Font issue in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, encoding

I have been having trouble displaying text on some webpages in Google Chrome recently.
Instead of having the text, I get like ugly checkboxes.
I don't recall having installed an extension that could have done that. In fact, I have no new extension.

[image]

In the *Chrome Menu > More Tools > Encoding*, *Autodetect* is checked.
And even if I manually select the good encoding for the website, it doesn't change anything.

Here is some examples of link :

- http://www.snopes.com/
- https://openclassrooms.com/dashboard

By the way, I am on Windows 10.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: What about other browsers? BTW, may be worth giving some sample URL   the issue appears where…

Comment: Other browsers work fine. And you were right, I added some links. Thank you.